# Grouping of jv_commits per transaction

Tags: java, javers

Is there a way of knowing which jv_commits are done in a single db transaction? It looks like a jv_commit is being created per flush, not per transaction. Could it be possible to add another identifier (column) to determine the db transaction in which it happened?

Example:

```
*** BEGIN (DB Transaction) ***
Update entity A (student.setName(...))
Flush entity A

Update Entity A again (student.setSurname(...))
Flush entity A again
*** COMMIT ***
```

If we understood the flow correctly, this example will generate 2 entries in the jv_commit and 2 entries in the jv_snapshot.

Is it possible to know that the 2 entries in the jv_commit table have been performed in the same db transaction?

Comment: this question is unclear, JaVers knows nothing about Yours (clients) transactions and flushes. Moreover, Stack is not a good place for posting feature requests like : Could it be possible to add another identifier (column) to determine the db transaction in which it happened?